# Is there some sort of gun (or a way) to decorate cookies with chocolate chips or nuts?

Tags: chocolate, cookies, nuts, decorating

I've started producing 1000 cookies a day, and I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to decorate cookies faster with chocolate chips or nuts than doing it by hand.

Some sort of gun or something that would push/throw nuts and chocolate chips?

Note: the photo shows peanut butter cookies topped with peanuts

thanks
[image]

Comment: The difficulty is that such a device would have to be set up quite precisely for the decoration being used. The chances of getting 0 or 2 when you want 1 would be quite high. A jam would take longer to clear than putting dozens of chocolate chips on cookies.

Comment: If you're placing one at a time, as it looks in the photo, it might be a little quicker to pick up a small handful, use your thumb to control them and drop one-by-one on cookies, and go back to press them all in later.

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the scale you desire.

**Industrial Scale**

---

From my quick youtube research, it seems like most commercial cooking making machines use an extrusion approach and are focused on dough deposition. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-R9nYHNTAE.

A machine like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP6WuXUKK_M, is the most promising that I have found. There is probably some clever mechanism that could, instead of punching out the middle of the cookies, deposit a chocolate chip or nut.

**Personal Scale**

---

This is harder, because of the inherent variability in environment and types of use. I doubt something already exists/haven't been able to find it. However, I have a couple of preliminary ideas. You need several parts:

- hopper to hold chips/nuts
- mechanism to deposit/press chip or nut into the dough
- barrel or something similar to connect the two parts.

Airsoft or paintball guns have hoppers that deal with similar style objects and are designed for handheld use. You could start by researching loading mechanisms for these guns.

The hardest part is designing the mechanism that will actually press the chip into the cookie, because of the delicate nature of the operation.

If you wish to discuss this further, feel free to contact me using the information on my profile.